# how to match the number of elements of matrix used in find function matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have written a function to assign training examples to their closest centroids as part of a K-means clustering algorithm. It seems to me that the dimensions are satisfied and the code runs correctly at times. But frequently, I get the error

> In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be
>   the same.

for the line

```
idx(i) = find(dist == value);
```

Here is the code

```
function idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids)

K = size(centroids, 1);
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);
dist = zeros(K, 1);

for i = 1:size(X,1)
   for j = 1:K
       dist(j) = sum((X(i,:) - centroids(j,:)).^2);
   end
   value = min(dist);
   idx(i) = find(dist == value);
end
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: rayryeng has answered your question correctly, but you might be interested in trying a vectorized approach `[~, idx] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, permute(centroids, [3,2,1])).^2,2),[],3)` which lets you skip all the loops, the pre-allocation and temporary matrices and can even be condensed into a single line.

Comment: @Dan Good idea :)... it was late at night and I didn't have time to write down the vectorized solution. This is a good comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are potentially finding **more than one** cluster that share the same distance to a query point.  `find` determines **all** values that satisfy the Boolean condition as the argument.  `idx(i)` implies that you are assigning a **single** value to the location of the `idx` array but `find` may yield more than one value and that gives the assignment error that you are seeing.

Instead use the second output argument of `min` which determines the **index** of **first time** the smallest value occurs, which is exactly what you want to accomplish:

```
function idx = findClosestCentroids(X, centroids)

K = size(centroids, 1);
idx = zeros(size(X,1), 1);
dist = zeros(K, 1);

for i = 1:size(X,1)
   for j = 1:K
       dist(j) = sum((X(i,:) - centroids(j,:)).^2);
   end
   [~,idx(i)] = min(dist); %// Change
end
```